# Do you get an extra slot for the master sword?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was playing Legend of Zelda Breath of The Wild. I got 13 hearts and I went to the Korok forest; I had 2 empty weapon slots. I pulled out the Master Sword but I still had those two empty weapon slots. I know that the Master Sword has its own slot but the thing is, did the Master Sword take one of the two spots and gave a new one or did the Master Sword come with its own spot meaning the Master Sword did not go in those two empty slots?

Comment: Is there really any difference between those two choices? Slots don't have identity - any slot is as good as any other.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Possibly a slight difference depending on order? If a new slot is given first, and the Master Sword is put in it, that's fine.  If the slot is given *afterwards*, then you might fail to pick up the Master Sword if you already had a full complement of weapons

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Master Sword has its own hidden slot, which can't be used by another weapon. So it was never accounted for in your two free weapon slots.